# How to write two media quires in a single css file?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following code in my css file

```css
@media (max-width:1000px) and (min-width:400px) {
    .tooltiptext {
        margin-left: 10em !important;
    }
    .homeInternetToolTip .tooltiptext i {
        left: 9% !important;
    }
}​

@media (min-width:1000px) and (max-width:1400px) {
    .tooltiptext {
        margin-left: 3em !important;
    }
}​
```

I am getting a error at 2nd query stating '{'} is needed.

Comment: It looks like your code contains some [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) characters. Could that be causing problems? See [Hidden characters in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537851/hidden-characters-in-css).

Comment: Here's a nifty tool to [view non-printable unicode characters](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php). See the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgV6E.png).

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to have an issue. Please find the code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      @media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 400px) {
        .tooltiptext {
          margin-left: 10em !important;
        }
        .homeInternetToolTip .tooltiptext i {
          left: 9% !important;
        }
      }
      @media (min-width: 1000px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
        .tooltiptext {
          margin-left: 3em !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as many `@media` queries as you want in a single css file, or also inside style tag. But when I copied your code in editor your `}` bracket at the end have some character code issue, either it is some other character that looks like `}`, or it have an invisible whitespace character after it making it not actually a `}`. So in your code remove the last bracket and type again from keyboard, don't copy from anywhere.